# Why is POSTMAN returning "None is not of type 'object'" when sending a POST request with body content?

Tags: python, api, http, swagger, postman

I use Swagger in order to build a Rest Api. One of the endpoint is /register which is defined in swagger.yaml as follows:

```
/register:
     post:
      tags:
      - "User"
      summary: "Registers the User"
      description: "..."
      operationId: "register_user"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "username"
        description: "Register data"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/username_1"
      responses:
        201:
          description: "User registered."
        404:
          description: "invalid input, object invalid"
      x-swagger-router-controller: "swagger_server.controllers.user_controller"
```

and the definition of the object:

```
username_1:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      username:
        type: "string"
      password:
        type: "string"
      email:
        type: "string"
      language:
        type: "string"
```

The register_user function does nothing yet.

```
def register_user(self):  
return 'do some magic!'
```

In Postman I add in the Body- form-data field the values:

```
KEY       VALUE
username  a
password  a
email     a
language  a
```

and after send I receive

```
{
  "detail": "None is not of type 'object'",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "type": "about:blank"
}.
```

As far as I figured it out until now the issue is the fact that the body is not sent via Postman. If I change in definitions for example

```
username_1:
    type: "string"
    #properties:
      #username:
        #type: "string"
      #password:
        #type: "string"
      #email:
        #type: "string"
      #language:
        #type: "string"
```

object to string the error transforms to

```
"None is not of type 'string'".
```

Hereby a screenshot of the Postman config: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7udd.png and one of the headers https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evkcr.png

As a final observation, the GET requests (which do not require additional parameters work perfectly).
Do you have any idea how to solve the problem? Thank you a lot!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evkcr.png

Comment: How did you configure the request in Postman? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Hellp Helen, thank you very much for the interest I added the screenshot. I also tried different methods to send the body (form-data or raw) and also tried to CURL in terminal... all with the same result

Comment: Could you share the Headers tab? This error seems to raise when the Content-Type header isn't set.

Comment: Hi Arlemi! The headers screenshot is now uploaded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evkcr.png